# Error in numpy argmax with sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using np.argmax function in one of my python programme for one of my data frame which is completely sparse matrix.my data frame contains 253 rows & 22 column. The head function return this sample data set

```
  var1                     var2     Var3  var4 ... .. var18  var19 ... var22
    0                        0       0     0   ......  0      1    ...  0
    0                        0       0     0   ......  0      0    ...  1
    0                        0       1     0   ......  0      0    ...  0
    0                        0       0     1   ......  0      0    ...  0
    0                        0       0     0   ......  1      0    ...  0
```

I'm using following code

```
y=np.argmax(train_y, axis=1)
```

While running this code I'm getting error message

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 253), indices imply (22, 253)
```

Can you expert please help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works fine for me when I use -

```
y=np.argmax(train_y.values, axis=1)
```

The `np.argmax` is a numpy function, passing in a dataframe could be causing this error. Instead convert it into a numpy nd array using the `.values` attribute of dataframes

Comment: Thank you. It works after converting it in numpy array